# Start/stop Windows Service A also Start/stop Windows service B

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, dependencies

I created two Windows services A and B, and would like to add dependency between them
so that I can:

1. Start service A (service B starts automatically)
2. Stop service A (service B stops automatically)

However, the command `sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB` only works for:

1. Start service A (service B starts automatically)
2. Stop service B (service A stops automatically)

Is there any way to make service B stop automatically when I stop service A?

Answer (score 5):

A dependency indeed only would work in a way that stopping service **B** would stop service **A**. If this is not what you want, dependencies are not for you and you would need something outside of the built-in service control mechanism doing this work. [Using WMI to subscribe to an event triggered by the service stop command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and some scripting to do the checks and stop the other service should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If A is dependent on B then all that means is that A needs B to be running therefore
- If you start A then it will automatically start B first
- If you stop B then A will be stopped first

If you stop A there is no reason for B to stop - if you have access to the source code of service A you could get it to stop B programatically when itself is stopped.